# How can I mark certain commits in my repo as "important" and display them on a timeline?

Tags: git, github

I'm looking for a way to create a timeline of important commits.
For example, if I have commits that are changing configurations in my project, I want to mark them, so I can visually see a timeline of critical changes in my project, for future troubleshooting.

I tried 2 methods, but both are not good enough:

1. Use a label for the commit's PR. The problem here is that GitHub cannot sort by "commit date" so I don't get the timeline I want.
2. Use a tag - that's not good either because I cannot assign the same tag for multiple commits.

Comment: If the messages are set in stone (as they are after the fact), your choices are limited to tags, notes, and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just have a keyword in the commit msg and filter the log?

```
git log --pretty=oneline --grep=awesomesauce
```

If you wanted it to be represented visually, you could add a workflow and/or job filtering the commits with the 'awesomesauce' keyword and render it as a [mermaid diagram](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid) in a markdown file.

Comment: Cool idea but I can't change the name of old commits that are already in the repo...

Comment: Ah - you need to retro fit the information. How about labelling the PR's, like you've tried, and pull out the PR information either via the GitHub API or the GH cli tool from a workflow. That way you can sort it and render it however you want it and still be able to retrofit the information.